# Align cells via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Can I ask help to please write a VBA code that aligns the cells according to their value? Example in the image:

I need to compare values from Column A against column E and move rows up and down until all are aligned. Obviously values on B and F need to move accordingly. Some values on both columns might not have a match, so in that case blank cells should be on the other columns within the same row. Also, cells with same font /background color need to be aligned to the same row.

The image has the original columns to the left and the desired outcome to the right.

I have tried several codes, the best one is below, but still not doing what I need. Anyone able to help me please? Thanks a lot.

[image]

```
Sub AlignMatches()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim matchRowA As Range, matchRowE As Range
    Dim matchFound As Boolean

    ' Define the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TEST")
    
    ' Get the last row
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop from the first to the last row
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        matchFound = False
        
        ' If A and E don't match and both have font color 0
        If ws.Cells(i, 1).Font.Color = 0 And ws.Cells(i, 5).Font.Color = 0 _
        And ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ws.Cells(i, 5).Value Then

            ' Check column A for a match to the E cell
            Set matchRowE = ws.Range("A:A").Find(ws.Cells(i, 5).Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
            
            ' If match found in column A
            If Not matchRowE Is Nothing Then
                If matchRowE.Font.Color = 0 Then
                    ' Move values from E & F to the matchRow
                    ws.Cells(matchRowE.Row, 5).Value = ws.Cells(i, 5).Value
                    ws.Cells(matchRowE.Row, 6).Value = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
                    ws.Cells(i, 5).ClearContents
                    ws.Cells(i, 6).ClearContents
                    matchFound = True
                End If
            End If
            
            ' If no match was found above, Check column E for a match to the A cell
            If Not matchFound Then
                Set matchRowA = ws.Range("E:E").Find(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
                If Not matchRowA Is Nothing Then
                    If matchRowA.Font.Color = 0 Then
                        ' Move values from A & B to the matchRow
                        ws.Cells(matchRowA.Row, 1).Value = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
                        ws.Cells(matchRowA.Row, 2).Value = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
                        ws.Cells(i, 1).ClearContents
                        ws.Cells(i, 2).ClearContents
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: and what is your current best code failing to do?

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for replying. I was traveling so I could just test it now.. Mine was only adding a few blank rows to the table on the right and nothing else. Yours is crashing excel. I tried yours with no changes and also tried with a line to run only on the desired sheet. thanks again, this is being difficult..

Comment: I gave you no code! How can it crash?

Answer (score 1):

Please try.

```
Option Explicit
Sub AlignTable()
    Dim i As Long, iDiff As Integer
    Const KEYCOL1 = 1 ' Comparing Col A vs Col D, modify as needed
    Const KEYCOL2 = 4
    i = 4 ' the first data row, modify as needed
    Do While (IsNumeric(Cells(i, KEYCOL1)) Or IsNumeric(Cells(i, KEYCOL2)))
        If Not IsNumeric(Cells(i, KEYCOL1)) Then
            Cells(i, KEYCOL1).Resize(1, 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        ElseIf Not IsNumeric(Cells(i, KEYCOL2)) Then
            Cells(i, KEYCOL2).Resize(1, 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        ElseIf Len(Cells(i, KEYCOL2)) > 0 Then
            iDiff = Val(Cells(i, KEYCOL1)) - Val(Cells(i, KEYCOL2))
            If iDiff > 0 Then
                Cells(i, KEYCOL1).Resize(1, 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            ElseIf iDiff < 0 Then
                Cells(i, KEYCOL2).Resize(1, 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            End If
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

[image]